# Using switch instead of merge

Tags: svn

At this moment, I am the only person working on a project in svn.  To stay legit, I am suppose to make changes to a branch and then merge those changes into trunk: so my branch and trunk are basically identical.  Currently I have two working copies, one for the branch and one for trunk.  I make the changes to the branch working copy and commit those, then I perform an svn merge on the trunk working copy from the branch location and then commit those changes. Question: can I change my process so that I only have one working copy and switch between the branch and trunk as follows?: 1) switch to branch, make changes and commit. 2) switch to trunk, commit.  3) repeat.

Comment: When you say to remain legit, what exactly does this mean?  Can you explain your release cycle and how long lived your branch is?  Basically how often do you branch and how often do you release?

Comment: @kevpie: Sure: this project has been 12 iterations (each iteration = 2 weeks), with 2 releases, the first at iteration 6, and the second current release at iteration 12. We branch at every release. The current release is for User Acceptance Testing (UAT), and we will have an iteration or two after UAT is complete to address customer feedback.  However, there are some high-visibility patches which I need apply to the current UAT release so I am doing those in the UAT branch, since theoretically new features could be introduced into trunk (except, I know they won't at this moment). Sound OK?

Comment: That sounds good. The skill of merging, patching etc. can only be learned by doing, so that is great.  In my experience of working with teams and as an individual, branch as late as possible.  Often this can mean not branching at all or branching in the future.  Do what ever you can to have the least number of active branches.  As long as your release versions are recorded or known you  can branch retroactively.  Meaning if you can't fix that critical bug and release from trunk, branch at the revision back where you created your UAT/Prod build and fix.  Next cycle release from trunk again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can with one additional step.

> 1) switch to branch, make changes and
>   commit. 2) switch to trunk, ***svn
>   merge* commited branch changes**,
>   commit. 3) repeat.

Comment: interesting additional step: please explain why this step is necessary. i.e. do i get additional meta-data performing the svn merge here? (because otherwise, my working copy should already be where I want it to be since the branch is always slightly ahead and I've just switched from it).

Comment: Once you have committed there are no modified changes that will persist after doing the switch.  Switch will change the checkout state from the path/revision to the target path/revision.  Only uncommitted changes will persist.  So the merge needs to apply changes from the previous commit.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this method and come back and mark yours as the correct answer if all goes well :)

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answers suggest, it is possible to stay with a single working copy by switching back and forth. There's nothing technically wrong with it, the operation is semantically identical. However, I would stay with the two working copies due to the following reasons:

- You would still have to svn merge the changes after the switch, because the switch reverts the (now committed) changes, as pointed out by the first answer.
- You can't avoid the merge by quickly copying your changes back after the switch, because the merge operation records meta data for the commit (svn:mergeinfo in svn >= 1.5, as linked in comment by Richard Fearn).
- With separate working copies, you have a 'clean' test environment for the branch, without your unversioned/uncommitted trunk changes.
- If you have uncommitted changes in your trunk working copy because you are working on the trunk when you need to fix the branch, there's a risk you accidentally commit something that was not supposed to be part of the fix. Twice - first in the branch commit, then in the trunk commit.

The only downside to having two working copies (at least that I can see) is that you may have to do an svn update before making the fix. You didn't mention your reason for wanting to change your process?

Comment: @Mikkel Blanne: +1 for the advice, but I'm going to try out the switch method.  The reason I want to change my process is because I am working on a Grails project with IntelliJ with a team in another company so a lot of my configurations and settings are different than what is in svn (or they aren't in svn at all) so I don't want to a) go through the process of changing all my configurations upon fresh check-out of a branch (there are 4 sub-projects total), and b) maintain multiple configurations for multiple working copies... seem reasonable?

Comment: So you do have local modifications :)  You could make a diff/patch file with the changes, and store it close by. Then you can always easily apply the patch to a fresh checkout. That works best if you don't need multiple configurations.

Comment: Interesting, can you point me to any resources about this technique?

Comment: But if you need local modifications in the branch anyway for testing it, then you don't gain a lot by the separate working copies, and I think I would go with the switch/change/commit/switch/merge/commit approach. Unless you happen to work on different things simultaneously.

Comment: On the command line: "svn diff > config.patch", then elsewhere "patch -p0 -i config.patch", depending on paths. TortoiseSVN has a GUI element for it. See an explanation for the command line version here: http://ariejan.net/2007/07/03/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-subversion/

Comment: "With separate working copies, you have a 'clean' test environment for the branch, without your unversioned/uncommitted trunk changes." this is the most important point! Switching is asking for troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, using [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html).

If your working copy is currently from the branch, and you've committed your changes to the branch:

```
svn switch svn://server/path/to/repo/trunk
```

Then to go back to the branch:

```
svn switch svn://server/path/to/repo/branches/xxx
```

Comment: Are there any drawbacks using the switch process compared to my current two-working-copies-merge process? i.e. does svn store any meta-data about revisions when I perform a merge which I'd be losing out on?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Depending on which version of Subversion you're using, metadata *is* stored, but this metadata is committed to the repository when you commit the merge (so it's retained across `switch`es). See this: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo